# Can we host blocks of more than one program in CM and RAM at the same time?If yes,which program helps to differentiate the blocks of separate programs

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

CM stands for Cache Memory. I was asked this question in an assignment. It asks which *program*  helps to differentiate the blocks of one program from the blocks of another program both in RAM and cache. I'm not sure if I know the *program* but I think mapping helps us to differentiate between blocks of different programs as different mappings divide the address into multiple fields each of which helps in identifying a specific thing.

Comment: Obviously yes, multi-tasking OSes have existed for a long time, and paging instead of swapping whole process images came soon after.  It's the kernel's job to keep track of which process is using which physical RAM.  A PIPT cache (or VIPT with some constraints) caches based on physical address, not virtual, so it just works transparently.

Comment: but I still didn't get as to which *program* helps to differentiate  the blocks of one program from the blocks of another program both in RAM and cache. Is kernel that *program*?

Comment: Yes, it's the kernel.  And yes, you can call it a program if you want.  Normally you don't, so there is no program (other than the kernel) which tracks physical memory allocation.  Especially on a machine with virtual memory, so separate processes don't have to avoid stepping on each other, they just each have their own virtual address space.